# OrientDb Studio requires RuntimePermission.createClassLoader

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I'm able to start the OrientDb studio using and embedded (plocal) server. However, I have to grant permissions to RuntimePermission.createClassLoader. I'd rather not grant that permission and I may not need a class loader; hot redeployment may not fit my needs and the server will be embedded (not independent from my application).

Is it possible to load OrientDb Studio without a class loader?

Here is my code to start the server:

```
OServer server;    
System.setProperty("ORIENTDB_HOME", getGraphDatabaseDirectoryPath());
server = OServerMain.create();
server.startup(orientServerConfigFile.getInputStream());
server.activate();
```

orientServerConfigFile points to my confile. Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <orient-server>
    <network>
      <protocols>
        <protocol implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary" name="binary"/>
        <protocol name="http" implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpDb"/>
    </protocols>
    <listeners>
        <listener protocol="binary" socket="default" port-range="2424-2430" ip-address="0.0.0.0"/>
        <listener protocol="http" port-range="2480-2485" ip-address="0.0.0.0">
            <commands>
                <command implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.get.OServerCommandGetStaticContent" pattern="GET|www GET|studio/ GET| GET|*.htm GET|*.html GET|*.xml GET|*.jpeg GET|*.jpg GET|*.png GET|*.gif GET|*.js GET|*.css GET|*.swf GET|*.ico GET|*.txt GET|*.otf GET|*.pjs GET|*.svg">
                    <parameters>
                        <entry value="Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate\r\nPragma: no-cache" name="http.cache:*.htm *.html"/>
                        <entry value="Cache-Control: max-age=120" name="http.cache:default"/>
                    </parameters>
                </command>
            </commands>
        </listener>
    </listeners>
</network>
<users>
    <user resources="*" password="root" name="root"/>
    <user resources="connect,server.listDatabases,server.dblist" password="guest" name="guest"/>
</users>
<properties>
    <entry value="1" name="db.pool.min"/>
    <entry value="50" name="db.pool.max"/>
    <entry value="true" name="profiler.enabled"/>
</properties>
```

Comment: Hi, can you post your code?